# ASP.NET Data binding in aspx vs code behind

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Could anyone tell me if there is a performance difference when binding controls to an aspx page as opposed to binding a control in code behind .cs files.

I prefer to use Literals if i'm honest, but am i wasting resource?

In an example like this :-

ASPX Page

```
 <p>
    <b><%#Item.StockKeepingUnit.Product.Name %></b>
 </p>
```

Or Like this with code behind :-

```
 <p>
    <b><asp:Literal id="ltlProductName" runat="server"</b>
 </p>
```

code behind :-

```
ltlProductName.Text = Item.StockKeepingUnit.Product.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a `label` element because it will turn it into a `html label` element with the correct attribute targeting your `control`, so if you click on the label it automatically sets your cursor inside the target control.

Use the `literal` unless having the text wrapped in a span would be beneficial for `css styles`.